# Interpreter not working

Tags: python, interpreter

```
def main():
cmd = (raw_input('#>>'))
if cmd=="SND_CMD_CREDITS":
    print "This language is made by Biohazard166 (Bioclassic23) or Dreadlurker36"
    main()

if cmd=="SND_CMD_HELP":
  print"Unfinsihed"
main()
if cmd=="SND_CMD_VER":
  print"This language is in VrPre-Alpha TEST PHASE 1"
  main()

else:
    print cmd,
    print " unknown command."
    main()
    print "Dreadscript Shell"
    main()
```

everything from the SND_CMD_VER down does not work it does not even display an error message at all as the error msg is  "unknown command" is the scripting wrong or is there a bug thats so obvious it makes me look like an idiot?

Comment: If that's the actual indentation I'm surprised the program runs at all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your posted code won't run at all.  "does not work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: ok sorry sir should i make it more specific?

Comment: Please correct your indentation and show the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your [indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) and make sure your program flows through `if` statements correctly.

Even first 2 lines should throw error now:

```
def main():
cmd = (raw_input('#>>'))
```

The correct notation is:

```
def main():
    cmd = (raw_input('#>>'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation are horrendus. Let me re-write your entire program.

```
def main():
    cmd = (input('#>>'))
    if cmd=="SND_CMD_CREDITS":
        print("This language is made by Biohazard166 (Bioclassic23) or Dreadlurker36")
        main()

    if cmd=="SND_CMD_HELP":
        print("Unfinsihed")
        main()
    if cmd=="SND_CMD_VER":
        print("This language is in VrPre-Alpha TEST PHASE 1")
        main()

    else:
        print(cmd),
        print(" unknown command.")
        main()
        print("Dreadscript Shell")
        main()

main()
```